# Pick date from cell and use as a file handle while saving

Tags: vba, excel, date, macros

A2=201604

I am trying to pick up value from a Cell(Date) and use the same for saving the file.

But while saving instead of the date a value is being printed, see code below:

```
Dim part1 as string
part1 = Range("A2").Value

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xxx- " & Format(part1, "MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsx" , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Are you saying instead of the file being saved, `part1` is being printed? Like to the immediate window? Do you have a print statement somewhere?

Comment: no, the file handle prints xxx-1234 (some value) instead of xxx-Apr-2016

Comment: I need the date which is present in the cell A2. format (date, "MMM-YYYY") will print the current date

Comment: What is in the cell? I just tried it using the Excel formula `Today()` in `A1` with `Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), "MMM-YYYY")` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

201604 is not a date. It is just a number.

You could use something like

myDate = "01/" & right(a2,2) & "/" left(a2,4)

string yourAnswer = format(myDate, "MMM-YYYY")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're prematurely casting the `Date` into a `String` by using the `part1` variable, so the 'date' is already broken and not recognisable as a date by the time it hits  your `Format()` call.

Either declare `part1` as a `Date` or just skip the whole `part1` declaration and insert `Range('A2').Value` directly into the `Format()` call.